# Android: What is the default textsize of an EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, text-size

Simple question: I want to know what the default textsize of an EditText is. Does anyone know?

Comment: This will depend on the Android version, the chosen theme, possibly the screen size, and possibly the specific device (latter due to manufacturer tinkering). You are welcome to look through the Android source code, particularly files like https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml to determine basic possibilities.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try

```
mEditText.getTextSize()
```

it will return in px to convert on sp

```
float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
 sp =  px/scaledDensity;
```

Comment: This just returns the textsize in px, not in dip or sp or whatever is used.

Comment: added formula to convert to sp

Comment: Okay, thanks, this returns me 18.0sp, so I bet that's it.

Comment: for me also it's 18